# Package import - Target of URI does not exists

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Please check my project:

https://github.com/MaximGo/WebTech_Projekt.git

In the file 'tetrisclient.dart' I want to import the generated package from the lib-folder.

```
import 'package:tetris/tetris.dart';
```

But I get the Erro 'Target of URI does not exists'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason you deleted your  previous question to create the same again? There is an `edit` link below your question, just below the [dart] tag.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried to use onlye lowercase filenames. But it only works once time. But I have the same problem again. Sorry!

Comment: Using lowercase was just a general hint,  not specific to your problem. My answer to your problem  was using `pub get` like Alexanders.

Comment: try "pub cache repair", this should help

Comment: @ashokd how to run "pub cache repair"?

Comment: its pub command like "pug get" we can repair cached libraries using "pub cache repair"

Comment: @ashokd Yes but I don't know how to run 'pub cache repair' in the cmd of windows. I tried to delet the pub cache in the AppData und run 'pub get' is it the same?
If yes - It doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterP use > flutter pub cache repair

Answer (score 47):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it and resolved it. But anyone that runs into this, simply close your project and reopen it. That solved it for me. I'm using Android Studio.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem when using Visual Code and following the Write your first app tutorial. This issue was resolved by just closing and reopening the project.

Comment: Was scratching my head on this! - In the end restarting VSCode did the trick!

Comment: you can also run pub get from command palette instead of re-starting VSCode

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Android Studio do like this:

[image]

- Click on Dart Analysis on the bottom
- Click on the Restart Dart Analysis Server icon on the left side of the window.

The errors will be fixed

Answer (score 4):

Solution: restart Android Studio. Or: just close and reopen project.

Had similar problem. For anyone who want to investigate, here my steps.
I decided to try that library https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider

I added dependency and download package via Android Studio. I also see path_provider.dart in External Libraries in my project. So, the file exist! But Studio show me an error "Target of URI doesn't exist" - how to fix it?

```
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

I use example code from path_provider project: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider#-example-tab-

Answer (score 3):

Run [pub get](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-get.html). If you use WebStorm you can do it using corresponding action from the pubspec.yaml file context menu.

Comment: No I use the Dart Editor. I tried to run pub get but I get the same error again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying code from codelabs by Google. You need to take care of remember spaces.

E.g. in `pubspec.yaml`

this:

```
flutter:
  sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  english_words: ^3.1.0   # add this line
```

is not this:

```
flutter:
  sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  english_words: ^3.1.0   # add this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Just **Close project and VSCODE** it will work

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS Code.
What worked for me was clicking on the option it recommends that seems dumb at first time: create file 'file_name.dart'
It merged an initialized file with the one that had in that location. I deleted the unnecessary stuff that is generated, and it was good to go.

I tried everything else I found on many pages over the internet. Diverse kinds of commands. Reopening, changing locations. Reinstalled the plugins.

EDIT 1: False alarm, it is temporary. But still, the quickest method, especially if you use CTRL + Z after it merged. I can't fix it OMG

EDIT 2: I opened now on Android Studio, and it said the file was in the wrong encoding. I changed the encoding (it has a button to select another one), and the errors disappeared!! (at least until now)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that dart:mirrors library is no more supported. See here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem while using Visual Studio Code. Had to close and re-open the VS Code but it didn't work out for me. But opening the file by typing `code .` to the command line solved my issue.