# Flutter doesn't recognize valid imports

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

This just started happening randomly. The app runs fine, but most valid imports are not recognized. This is happening with packages and local files.

I've restarted and Android Studio, did a pub cache repair, flutter clean, uninstalled and reinstalled the android studio flutter plugin, tried opening in VScode, nothing is helping.

Other people on my team have pulled my same repo and they are not experiencing this problem.

Any Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you added dependencies in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52037403/6891637)

Comment: yes and yes, its not even recognizing local files in my project

Comment: @Derek Hannah Goto your pubspec.lock and look for those import that are not working remove them and run pub get again

Comment: Its being caused by .symlinks dir, if I delete . symlinks and do a packages get it recognizes the imports. Once I build iOS and the .symlinks folder is generated it stops recognizing the imports

Comment: @DerekHannah where can I find this .symlinks dir

Comment: for me this answer worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/45339159/9986177.
In the end it was vscode

Answer (score 3):

Most of the issue should be resolved by android studio "invalidate cache and restart" action.

Answer (score 0):

I faced to this problem and restarted Android Studio some times and it continue still not working. So, I changed the name of import and putted just the name of the file. Example: `import 'authentication.dart'`. Without the whole 'package:.../'.

If you're importing packages, try this in the terminal (same directory of the project):

with pub:

```
$ pub get
```

with flutter:

```
$ flutter pub get
```

Answer (score -1):

Its work for me

Bottom Menu -> Dart Analysis -> Restart Dart Analysis Server

OR try

`flutter pub get`

Until recognize valid imports