# importing flutter firebase user dashboard dart

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use `import 'package:flutter_firebase_auth/user_dashboard.dart';` in my project but it says that Target of URI does not exist. I could not find a solution nor any info about that online. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this package on pubspec.yaml and then get this package? Is this "user_dashboard" name correct?

And you can check this question to find answers. [Package import - Target of URI does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31003528/14857152)

Answer (score 0):

At times there's a problem while importing the package. Check wheater you have imported it as `firebase_auth: ^1.1.3` and not `firebase_auth: 1.1.3`